# How to receive payments in target currency

Tags: paypal

I have a website that accepts payment with several currencies, using the Paypal Classic API.

I want that, when the payment is done, it gets automatically converted to the business account default currency (in this case, BRL).

That way I won't have two (or more) balances, for instance: BRL and USD.

I need everything to be in a singular currency, for sake of consistency.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an option that you can easily select in the business account, at a per-account level.

In fact, whenever a PayPal account is paid in a new currency, PayPal holds the funds until the account holder decides whether to open a balance in that currency or to convert payments made in that currency to the account's default currency.

You cannot make this election on a per-transaction basis (e.g. you have both BRL and USD balances, but ask that a particular subset of transactions coming in as USD are automatically converted to BRL). Of course, you can specify BRL as the transaction of the payment (and buyers who only have USD will have those USD converted to BRL), or you can transfer currency balances within the account (e.g. if you get a $30 USD payment that you want to have turned into BRL, you can convert $30 USD to BRL).